# Creating structured hive table with unstructured GPS packets in csv format

Tags: regex, csv, hadoop, filter, hive

I have a csv file like mentioned below.

`VTS,51,0071,9739965515,NM,GP,INF01,V,19,072219,291014,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,07AE
VTS,01,0097,9739965515,SP,GP,18,072253,V,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,0.0,0.0,291014,0000,00,4000,11,999,169,B205
VTS,51,0071,9739965515,NM,GP,INF01,V,18,072311,291014,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,C24E
VTS,01,0097,9739965515,NM,GP,19,072311,V,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,0.0,0.0,291014,0000,00,4000,11,999,171,B358
VTS,51,0071,9739965515,NM,GP,INF01,V,18,072319,291014,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,012F
VTS,51,0071,9739965515,NM,GP,INF01,V,19,072326,291014,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,B2E6
VTS,01,0097,9739965515,NM,GP,18,072326,V,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,0.0,0.0,291014,0000,00,4000,11,999,173,EAA0
VTS,51,0071,9739965515,NM,GP,INF01,V,18,072333,291014,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,9896
VTS,51,0071,9739965515,NM,GP,INF01,V,18,072340,291014,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,9B23`

This has to be mapped with fields:

`pkt_header,gprs_pkt_id,pkt_length,sim_no,msg_id,gprs_pkt,gsm_sig_strength,utc_time,pkt_validation,latitude,direction_n_s,longitude,direction_e_w,speed,track_angle,utc_date,fuel_adc_values,ignition,odometer_values,supply_int,battery_adc,pkt_id,check_sum`

The second field i.e. gprs_pkt_id with value 01 depicts a valid packet. My used case is to filter the csv data only for valid packets, for which I am using regex, but I am not able to get the entire data. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

The used Hive query is shown below.

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABlE sky_track_testing1(
pkt_header STRING,
gprs_pkt_id STRING,
pkt_length STRING,
sim_no STRING,
msg_id STRING,
gprs_pkt STRING,
gsm_sig_strength STRING,
utc_time STRING,
pkt_validation STRING,
latitude STRING,
direction_n_s  STRING,
longitude  STRING,
direction_e_w STRING,
speed STRING,
track_angle  STRING,
utc_date STRING,
fuel_adc_values STRING,
ignition  STRING,
odometer_values STRING,
supply_int  STRING,
battery_adc  STRING,
pkt_id  STRING,
check_sum STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "^(VTS,01).*$"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/user/root/sky_track';`

This is definitely a wrong query. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use [Pig](https://pig.apache.org/) for this:

```
a = load '/user/root/sky_track' as (pkt_header,gprs_pkt_id,pkt_length,sim_no,msg_id,gprs_pkt,gsm_sig_strength,utc_time,pkt_validation,latitude,direction_n_s,longitude,direction_e_w,speed,track_angle,utc_date,fuel_adc_values,ignition,odometer_values,supply_int,battery_adc,pkt_id,check_sum);
b = filter a by gprs_pkt_id == '01';
store b into '/user/root/sky_track_valid';
```

Comment: this pig script is generating output folder and file but write nothing into it..anyhow i got it done with slight modification in the script and it working...

Comment: `L = Load '/user/skytrack/syslog' using PigStorage(',')
as (
pkt_header:Chararray,
gprs_pkt_id:INT,
pkt_length:Chararray,
sim_no:Chararray,
msg_id:Chararray,
gprs_pkt:Chararray,
gsm_sig_strength:INT,
utc_time:Chararray,
pkt_validation:Chararray,
latitude:DOUBLE,
direction_n_s:Chararray,
longitude:DOUBLE,
direction_e_w:Chararray,
speed:DOUBLE,
track_angle:DOUBLE,
utc_date:Chararray,
fuel_adc_values:INT,
ignition:INT,
odometer_values:INT,
supply_int:INT,
battery_adc:INT,
pkt_id:INT,
check_sum:Chararray);
VC = filter L by (gprs_pkt_id == 1);
dump VC;
STORE VC INTO 'input/valid/packet123456';`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As per the above answer Pig will be very well suited for your data. you can give a try in pig. If you are interested in hive, please see the below example(regex is not needed for your dataset).

```
hive> CREATE  TABLE sky_track_testing1(
    > pkt_header STRING,
    > gprs_pkt_id STRING,
    > pkt_length STRING,
    > sim_no STRING,
    > msg_id STRING,
    > gprs_pkt STRING,
    > gsm_sig_strength STRING,
    > utc_time STRING,
    > pkt_validation STRING,
    > latitude STRING,
    > direction_n_s  STRING,
    > longitude  STRING,
    > direction_e_w STRING,
    > speed STRING,
    > track_angle  STRING,
    > utc_date STRING,
    > fuel_adc_values STRING,
    > ignition  STRING,
    > odometer_values STRING,
    > supply_int  STRING,
    > battery_adc  STRING,
    > pkt_id  STRING,
    > check_sum STRING
    > ) 
    > ROW FORMAT
    > DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    > LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE;
OK
Time taken: 0.1 seconds

hive> select *from sky_track_testing1 where gprs_pkt_id='01';
OK
VTS 01  0097    9739965515  SP  GP  18  072253  V   0000.0000   N   00000.0000  E   0.0 0.0 291014  0000    00  4000    1999    169 B205
VTS 01  0097    9739965515  NM  GP  19  072311  V   0000.0000   N   00000.0000  E   0.0 0.0 291014  0000    00  4000    1999    171 B358
VTS 01  0097    9739965515  NM  GP  18  072326  V   0000.0000   N   00000.0000  E   0.0 0.0 291014  0000    00  4000    1999    173 EAA0
Time taken: 14.328 seconds
```